ice dispenser leaking and other ice/water dispenser issues in a new fridge
I bought a new fridge and the water dispenser is leaking, slowly. Outside, and looks like maybe inside too.
I've no idea what it's supposed to look like. Note: on the second picture it may look like the inside is dirty but it's not, it's just how the light reflects.
There are other symptoms, which may be related or not:

The ice actually won't dispense. When you push the ice dispenser button, you can hear the ice maker at work, but nothing is dispensed.
The water that comes out of the water dispenser is not cold, it's the same temperature as tap water.




As it's a new fridge. contact the store you bought it from or the company that made it and request that the problem be fixed under warranty.

With new stuff, you let the company fix problems.  If you try to fix, the warranty on it can be denied.

the first picture shows that the ice maker is leaking

the second picture shows a part of the ice dispenser, not the water dispenser

@jsotola thx, updated

Yes, it sounds like a warranty issue. I got a new compressor in my LG and my son got a new ice maker in his Samsung. All, covered free. Call the store you bought it from.

maybe you forgot to remove packing material or packing tape from the icemaker area

@jsotola I thought about that too but try as I might I couldn't find any tape or paper to remove. Neither could I find anything in the instruction specific to removing packing around the icemaker.

the icemaker may have a test button that makes it cycle through its dump and fill sequence
